# How to render 3D anamorphic panorama with a third perspective view?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

is it possible to render 3d anamorphic panorama with a third perspective view in one single movie?

I'd like to show the anamorphic motion graphic on the curved glass screen.
it should include the front, side, ceiling as well.

Here is the reference that I want to make.
[image: anamorphic installation in Seoul]

https://www.youtube.com/embed/dJCRxm-d14U

As you can see those images, those methods are already rendered as calculated distortion for giving 3d depth. Even it is only effective from the specific point to see, I want to test it as a mockup though.

I got information that a specification of this curved screen that 7,840 by 1,952 pixels of resolution. (also 80m width and 20m tall it is, but for making mockup, it’s not necessary.)

[image]

This is my testing modelling that some objects in internal space.

And it may need to connect more than two cameras' rendering
or make a projected camera with python script like below. Unfortunately, I have no idea to handle python code like that.
[image]
^ picture by [Martynas Žiemys](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/60759/martynas-%C5%BDiemys)

Also, most problem is it has to show a third perspective view.
[image]

Thanks!